# Can someone explain to me how the scope of the logical "OR" operator works in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

here's my code.

```
function getVowelCount(str) {
 let array = str.split("");
 let vowelCount = array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
   if (curr === 'a' || curr === 'e' || curr === 'i' || curr === 'o' || curr === 'u') {
     acc++
   } return acc
 }, 0);
 return vowelCount
}
```

I'm new to coding and I've started with Javascript. Could someone be so kind as to explain why I can't use `"(curr === 'a' ||'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u')"` in my if statement. I thought that would have been processed as; "If the current value is 'a' OR 'e' OR 'i' etc...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`===` has higher order of operations than `||`. 
Operators of equal order are evaluated left to right.

(see [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) for full order).

So `curr === 'a' ||'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u'` is equivalent to

`(((((curr === 'a') ||'e') || 'i') || 'o') || 'u')`

Which can be reduced to `curr === 'a' ? true : 'e'`.

Answer (score 1):

Just like there's an order of operations for math (multiplication/division before addition/subtraction), [javascript's operators have an order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). In `(curr === 'a' ||'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u')`, the highest priority is the `===`, so it starts by comparing `curr === 'a'`. This is going to result in either `true` or `false`. Let's assume `false`.

Next up there's all the `||`'s. These are done left to right, so it compares `false || 'e'`. Every string except for an empty string is "truthy", so `false || 'e'` is truthy as well.

It would continue moving to the right, except logical OR operators will short circuit once the outcome is guaranteed. So the whole expression is truthy.

---

Even if `||` had a higher precedence, it wouldn't make this work. With `'a' || 'e'`, both of those are "truthy", so it just takes the first truthy value, which is `a`. And this would repeat, meaning `'a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u'` is a complicated way of saying `'a'`.

```js
console.log('a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u')
```

Comment: > " So the whole expression is a `true`. " -- It's certainly truthy, but I think it's important to note that `||` chains return the first value that is truthy, rather than `true` itself, so in this case the whole expression is `'e'`, which is truthy (assuming `curr = 'b'` or something).

Comment: Fair enough. Updating.